# Why can't I access request attribute inside a decorator?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm using `request.POST.get('...')` inside my Django decorator (`@save_post_request`) whenever my form is submitted, on each tentative I get this same error

*(error with `request.<anything>`)*:

> AttributeError: 'collectData' object has no attribute 'POST'

My decorator is called on top of a `post()` function inside `CollectData` classBasedView.

```
#views.py
class collectData(View):
    template_name = 'collect_data.html'
    context = {...}

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        return render(request, self.template_name, self.context)


    @save_post_request
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        return redirect(reverse('collectData'))


#decorators.py
def save_post_request(function):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):

        title = request.POST.get('title') # <---
        ...
        return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
    wrap.__doc__ = function.__doc__
    wrap.__name__ = function.__name__
    return wrap
```

I'm not sure if a decorator can be called like so using `classBasedViews`, but I think it should be right, what is my mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First argument of inner function should be `self`:

```
def save_post_request(function):
    def wrap(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        title = request.POST.get('title') # <---
        ...
        return function(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
    wrap.__doc__ = function.__doc__
    wrap.__name__ = function.__name__
    return wrap
```

Comment: It worked! I've been using decorators without the "self" on top of the Class and was able to use request, didn't think that inside class I have to use self! Thank you.

Comment: @Lindow It's actually not a question of "inside class" or "outside class", but of matching the wrapper's signature with the decorated function's signature. Here your `post` function expects a `collectData` instance as first argument (`self`) and a request as second argument.

Comment: @neverwaloner: your decorator should pass `self` as first argument : `return function(self, request, *args, **kw)`.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I see! Thanks!