# throttle with function based views using Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to throttle my API routes but I am unable to do it with functions using Django Rest Framework. All the documentations are for class-based views.  I even tried a workaround as suggested here: [Django Rest Framework Scope Throttling on function based view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63454449/django-rest-framework-scope-throttling-on-function-based-view)
but it did not work.

Here is my code snippets:

Views:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from rest_framework.throttling import UserRateThrottle, AnonRateThrottle

# Create your views here.


def home(request):
    throttle_scope = 'perday'
    return render(request, 'home.html')

def search(request):
    throttle_scope = 'search'
    query = request.GET['query']
    response = requests.get('https://api.stackexchange.com//2.2/search/advanced?order=desc&sort=activity&q=' + query + '&site=stackoverflow')
    apiResponse = response.json()
    
    allData = []

    for eachtitle in apiResponse['items']:
        allData.append(eachtitle)

    paginator = Paginator(allData, 10)
    pageNumber = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    page = paginator.get_page(pageNumber)
    return render(request, 'search.html', {"eachdata": page, "query": query})
```

Settings of my project:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': [
        'example.throttles.BurstRateThrottle',
        'example.throttles.SustainedRateThrottle'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
        'perday': '2/min',
        'search': '5/day'
    }
}
```

I am not getting any errors, it just does not work. I have also added rest-framework in installed apps.

Comment: The views in the question return rendered HTML, they are not DRF API endpoints?

Comment: no, I am rendering it.